# Can not use iPhone due to Guided Access

Tags: iphone, performance, restart

After I accidentally clicked on **Guided Access**, my iPhone became unusable. I tried to shut my iPhone down but it won't do anything after I slide the bar to turn it off. I have an iPhone 11 and just updated to iOS 16.

Apparently, I enabled **Guided Access** at some point with 3 clicks on the side button (or maybe it was there already?) because I don't even know what that is. Yesterday, I added in **Accessibility**, the task to change the screen's brightness with 3 clicks of the side button.

When I did 3 clicks, it asked which one I wanted: **Guided Access** or change brightness. The second one worked fine but I did it again with **Guided Access** to see what it does and now I just can’t do anything with my iPhone, not even restart it.

Comment: The next thing to try is a force restart. That should work, otherwise [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Press and quickly release the volume up button.
> 2. Press and quickly release the volume down button.
> 3. Press and hold the side button.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph8903c3ee6/ios

Comment: Thank you so much, That worked! I was trying to turn off the iPhone sliding the button but of course, that didn't worked cause apparently, the touch screen function crashed. That's why it was not responding. Thank you again.